# creating a list with 2 entries for each element of an iterator

Tags: python, list, iterator

I'm looking for a more elegant way to do something like this:

```
[data[i/2] if i%2==0 else log10(data[i/2]) for i in xrange(len(data)*2)]
```

So if data was [1,10,100], I want to make a list:

```
[1,0,10,1,100,2]
```

fyi: this is for output to a csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [1,10,100]
itertools.chain(*((x,log10(x)) for x in data))
```

then make a list

Comment: I'd say this one would be the most efficient, and also pretty readable (once you understand what `chain` and the `*` are doing).
For those new to python, this needs to be preceded by something like 

`from numpy import *` and 

`import itertools`

Comment: Actually, this is the least efficient of the 3 posted - the nested list comprehension posted by Ignacio is the most efficient (9.87 us versus 12.2 us).  not that 2 microsends is much to worry about.  but for an interesting explanation of why, see this thread -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> data = [1, 10, 100]
>>> [x for y in data for x in (y, math.log10(y))]
[1, 0.0, 10, 1.0, 100, 2.0]
```

Comment: This is the kind of expression I read and think in my head "and Python was designed to be readable?  Riiiight."  Not saying it doesn't work or isn't clever... (or that I don't like Python, because I do.)  Only that parsing this kind of list comprehension in my head leads to a headache.

Comment: The problem with nested `for` loops is that you have to mentally execute the code to know what's going on... And this one is just to flatten the data

Comment: it's a wtf moment the first time you see one, but easy enough to decipher:  `for y in data: for x in (y, log(y)): yield x`

Comment: @wim: That's why it's unreadable, in my opinion. :) You have to skip past `x` and then read it, and finally come back to `x` to get the full picture.  I should be able to read mostly left-to-right; this construct forces me to start reading halfway into the expression, then loop around to the beginning.

Comment: yeah, definitely one of the less-than-readable python contructs .. but it's unambiguous at least, and i can't really think of any better way to do a nested list comprehension

Comment: hmm.. pretty cryptic with its mentioning x, then y, then x, then y again.. It effectively does the same thing as JBernardo's `[x for x in itertools.chain(*((x,log10(x)) for x in data))]` but the addition of `y` makes it harder to grasp..

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(([x, math.log10(x)] for x in data), [])
```

Comment: I can see what you're trying to do here, but this gives me `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'` and I've not been able to work out why..

Comment: Oops! Looks like numpy.sum() was interfering - bad habit of mine to do `from numpy import *`! Interesting that if you don't specify `[]` as initial value, `sum()` (the native, not the numpy sum()) starts summing with an initial (numeric) `0` and raises the TypeError above.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for answering my own question, but the answers here inspired me to play around a bit, and I came to something that is significantly faster than the above:

```
import itertools
import numpy
data = range(1,10000)
[x for y,z in itertools.izip(data,numpy.log10(data)) for x in (y, z)]
```

The point is that `numpy.log10()` is more efficient than calling `math.log10()` many times. With 10000 integers, I got 4.59 msec vs 32.8 msec for Ignacio's list comprehension, 32.9 msec for JBernaro's chain() and 482 msec for Karl's sum(). I guess the sum() version loses out when it allocates a length 2 list for every x-value.